# Create Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a little help. I have an expression that is

```
$orderline_val->products[$x]->product_options[2]->value
```

It generates a kind of string. What I need is a regular expression that removes every "new line" character, every (') apostrophy comma. On the other hand it also places a pipe on every 40th character.

Any help? I was thinking to use preg_replace but could not generate a right expression.

Here is the code that I tried.

```
str_replace("&,',/n/r", "+",$orderline_val->products[$x]->product_options[2]->value);
```

Let me know,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: `places a pipe on every 40th character` Before or after removing those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array("", ""), $orderline_val->products[$x]->product_options[2]->value);
$parts = str_split($str, 40); // Or 39...
$piped_str = implode("|", $parts);

// Not sure if you want the next line, but in any case:
$orderline_val->products[$x]->product_options[2]->value = $piped_str;
```

Comment: Is this what you needed?